# zero results behaviour in SELECT using executeAsync of mozIStorageStatement object,

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mozilla

I run a SQL SELECT statement using executeAsync function of mozIStorageStatement object, the thing is, when the statement get no results, the handleresult function of the callback doesn't run. Is this a normal behaviour or do I have a bug? If it is a normal behaviour, then how do I write a code that will run in the case we have zero results?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. The `handleResult` method is called only when results are available, which is never (when a query returns the empty set). You can handle this case in the `handleCompletion` method, which always executes, whether or not the query returns any rows.

Here's a throwaway example to demonstrate:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");  
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");  

var DBTest = {
    // chrome window loaded
    onload: function(e) {
        var appContent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
        appContent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
            try {
                var file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["cookies.sqlite"]);  
                var dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
                var stmt = dbConn.createStatement(
                        "SELECT * FROM moz_cookies WHERE name='trash'");
                stmt.executeAsync({  
                    handleResult: function(aResultSet) {  
                        alert("handleResult");
                    },  
                    handleError: function(aError) {  
                        alert("handleError: " + aError.message);  
                    },      
                    handleCompletion: function(aReason) {  
                        alert("handleCompletion: " + aReason);
                    }  
                });  
            } catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }, true);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", DBTest.onload, false);
```

The `aReason` parameter can have the following values:

- `REASON_FINISHED = 0` The statement has finished executing normally.
- `REASON_CANCELED = 1` The statement stopped executing because it was canceled.
- `REASON_ERROR = 2` The statement stopped executing because an
  error occurred.

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/MozIStorageStatementCallback